# Idiomatic way to chose shared memory or unix semaphore key

Tags: c, unix, shared-memory, semaphore

What is the idiomatic way to choose a key for `shmget` or `semget` functions?

How can I be sure that the same key isn't used by some other processes?

Yes. i know that a big random number is most likely not used by anyone else, but is't there a bulletproof way to choose it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you know that there is function `ftok` that let you obtain a key from a filepath. So the problem of having a "personal" key is to find a "personal" file. It is guaranteed to have different keys for different files. An idiom could be to create a temporary file (with the help of `tmpnam`?), or to create a file hidden in some private directory and use it with `ftok`.

Comment: Yes, that's the way i though about, but looks like too hackish for me. Isn't it a little bit weired create a file (ftok requres real existed file) just to get a key? But looks like it's the best option.

Comment: Don't look too hackish to me, afterall, there already is a space with unique ids, why not use it for many purpose? And an empty file consume so little space and cpu-time...

Comment: Note that ftok (naturally) does **not** guarantee different values for different files (and proj_id), but only same values for same files. That values are different for simultanously existing files is only a "should" in the manpage.

Comment: Wrong, Open Group: The ftok() function shall return the same key value for all paths that name the same file, when called with the same id value, **and return different key values when called with** different id values or with **paths that name different files** existing on the same file system at the same time.

Comment: This also only is a "shall". As soon as you have more than 2^24 files (32 bit key_t minus 8 bit project ID), there is no way to guarantee that. Considering that it is likely that the device ID plays a role too (the manpages suggest that), less than 2^24 files will suffice, maybe only 2^16 files are sufficient (my system currently has ~2^20 files on ``/``, a fresh debian has about 2^14) so that a collision *must* exist. And that only if inodes are assigned sequentially and re-used when freed. ftok is a 32-bit hash function so collisions *will* happen and one has to prepare for it.

Comment: `key_t` is not necessarily defined as 32 bits... And no, device id doesn't play any role as the guarantee is limited to files **on the same filesystem**. But I agree that in practice there can be some collision on some filesystems and OSes. Note: shall is a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Use both the flags `IPC_CREAT` and `IPC_EXCL` when allocating the shared memory or semaphore in the first place. The `shmget` command will fail if there already is a shared memory segment with the given key. Repeatedly try to get a shared memory segment with new random keys until you succeed.

Now you have to figure out the way to communicate the key you used to other processes. As you suggested using random numbers, I assume that you have such ways.